# input関数の指定した値の数を入力値に与える

Tags: python3

下記の入力値がありまして、3が列、5が行です。
Pythonの `input` 関数でこのように指定して入力値を出力するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

**入力値:**

```
3 5
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
```

実際私が書いたコードを下記に記します。

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
for _ in range(n):
    num_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

3の列は問題なく出来ましたが、行の方はいくつでも入力できるようになっています。

これを、3や4など、指定した値分入力値として与えたいと考えています。

**例1:**

```
2 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

**例2:**

```
2 4
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1
```

分かる方いましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「3が行数、5が列数」ではないですかね。`num_list = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: コードありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。
行数及び列数に関して再度調べます